# IE 10 controls not repainting

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where there is a multiselect control (a listbox).  There is a Clear button on the page, which calls a javascript function that sets the selectedIndex property of the select control to -1.  This ordinarily clears any selections in the control.

I have a customer who is using IE 10 on Windows 7.  When they hit the Clear button, nothing appears to happen.  But programmatically, the select is definitely cleared.  And if they mouse over the list box, the selections disappear.  So it seems to be an issue of the screen not repainting properly until forced to by the mouse over.

Is this a known issue?  Is there a way to force the browser to repaint the control?

Comment: Could you share some main code ?

Comment: Is it an angular app? I have had similar issues in IE10 while using angular. Guess this comes back to being able to see some code.

Comment: You can try to use developer tool-console from IE (Keyboard shortcut: F12) and check errors.

Comment: `<select name=arcompany id=arcompany style="height:expression(parent.document.body.offsetHeight - 125);width:70" size=2 multiple>
<option value="ABC">ABC</option>
<option value="DEF">DEF</option>
<option value="GHI">GHI</option>
<option value="JKL">JKL</option>
</select>`

Comment: `<input type=button name=myclear id=myclear value="Clear" onclick="doInvcClear()" style="width:100;margin-top:5;margin-bottom:5" />`

Comment: `function doInvcClear() {
 document.myform.arcompany.selectedIndex = -1;
}`

Comment: There are the two objects I mentioned, and the javascript function.  The only change I made was that the select box has way more than 4 items in it.  Enough so that the scrollbar cuts in.  But I'm not sure how that'll help.